# Dell E6500 virtualization BIOS settings

Tags: bios, virtualization, dell-latitude, vt-x

Do you have Any experience how virtualization related BIOS settings work In Dell E6500? I am using VMWare Workstation 6.5 and do not see any option to turn those “magic features” on.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[Dell Latitude E6500 virtualization BIOS option](http://siwike.blogspot.com/2009/02/dell-latitude-e6500-virtualization-bios.html)

> With BIOS A11 on the Dell Latitude E6500 with the Intel T9600 CPU, if you want to enable the Intel VT extensions so VMware Workstation can run a 64bit VM, you need to have the 'Trusted Execution' Virtualization BIOS option set to OFF.
>
> If you have it set to ON, the VMware CPU check says that the CPU supports 64bit but is turned off on the BIOS.

Some more discussions on this [Dell community thread](http://en.community.dell.com/forums/p/19238575/19513780.aspx).
You should check your processor model too.